# Eclipse headless build doesnt return error code

Tags: eclipse, build, build-automation, headless

I have an ant script that does a headless build using the following ant code

```
<java jar="${equinoxjar}" fork="true" failonerror="true"  logerror="true">
        <arg line="-application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -buildfile ${buildscript}" />

    </java>
```

However it seems that even if my code has compilation errors, the returncode from the java task does not return an error. Thus my builds in teamcity are still shown as successful, even though there are compilation errors.

How do i fix this?
The version of eclipse I am using to do the build is 3.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you 100% certain that you are building with 3.6.2? There was a bug like this in 3.6.0, but it was fixed in 3.6.1 release.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321386

Comment: Yes. The value of ${equinoxjar} is C:\eclipses\target\eclipse3.6.2\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar

Comment: I do notice that if i add a property javacFailOnError= true in the build.properties file, then the build does fail.
However I think it should fail without it too, if I am correct.

Comment: Re javacFailOnError=true. Based on your comment I went looking closer at my build script and sure enough I set this property in the java task when calling into antRunner.

Comment: umm by the 'java task' you mean setting the property in the build.properties file right? The java task doesnt have a javacFailOnError property.

Comment: <arg value="-DjavacFailOnError=true"/> in your <java> invocation.